# Azure Verizon Premium CDN - Stuck at Domain Name Validation (even after the SSL certificates are provisioned)

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am using Premium Verizon CDN, met with a peculiar case where-in the endpoint host name is HTTPs enabled (CDN provided certificate) but Azure Portal shows that it is still at Domain Name Validation. Enabling HTTPs was initiated on 1st Feb and from 2nd Feb the endpoint has a valid SSL certificate, but for some reason the Azure portal has not updated yet & still stuck at domain validation (its been close to 3 days now).

Has anyone encountered such a behavior yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, this is the reason that CDN provider could not find the domain owner information and could not verify the domain ownership when you enable HTTPS via use a CDN-managed certificate. For this, I may suggest that you could partially disclosure your domain owner information so that Verizon could verify the domain ownership as soon as possible. For more information, you could get the process of [validating the domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate#validate-the-domain).

If you don’t see your domain validated within an hour, you also could [open a support ticket.](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) They will contact the Verizon and confirm the domain information for you.